# Cairo rendering Arabic text in wrong direction

Tags: c, cairo

Cairo renders Arabic text left to right instead of right to left. Furthermore, the characters are not connected. Here's my code:

```
#include <cairo.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  cairo_t *c;
  cairo_surface_t *cs;
  cairo_font_face_t * ct;

  cs = cairo_image_surface_create (CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 500, 500);
  c = cairo_create (cs);

  cairo_select_font_face(c, "Arial",
      CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL,
      CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);

  cairo_set_font_size (c, 40);

  cairo_set_source_rgb (c, 255, 255, 255);
  cairo_move_to (c, 100, 100);
  cairo_show_text(c, "كيف الحال");

  cairo_surface_write_to_png (cs, "cairo.png");

  return 0;
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

The first letter 'ك' is shown as the first character on the left when it should be on the right. 'ك' should also be connected to 'ي'. All the characters are individually shown, like in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is [not possible with Cairo](https://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-text.html):

> The functions with text in their name form cairo's toy text API. The
> toy API takes UTF-8 encoded text and is limited in its functionality
> to rendering simple left-to-right text with no advanced features. That
> means for example that most complex scripts like Hebrew, Arabic, and
> Indic scripts are out of question.

Comment: In the next paragraph, the solution is described: use pango, which integrates with cairo to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, you have to use pangocairo. These libraries would always show up when I built something, but I never imagined I'd be using them!